# android: dump data from local xml file to SQLite database

Tags: android, xml

How can I copy my data from xyz.xml in my assets dir to my sqllite db during development in android platform

Comment: I think you need to write some class or method that will do that import for you. No one knows how the XML tags map to your database structure but you.

Comment: I'm looking for code to parse the xml data. the tutes are for rss feeds from the internet but i couldn't find any tutes to do the parsing from local xml file

Answer (score 1):

Something like this..

```
InputStream is;
Document dom = null;
is = getAssets().open("main.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
dom = builder.parse(is);
Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
XMLPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.id);
```